# How to return rows from postgresql where date greater than 24 hours ago

Tags: python, postgresql, datetime, sqlalchemy

I am trying to return all entries in my postgresql database where the date is greater than 24 hours ago.  What I have so far seems to only return dates that are within the same day.  I believe I have my database timezone set to EST and I thought I was dealing with it appropriately in my query.

```
@router.get("/day")#, response_model=schemas.Post)
def get_post( db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    now = datetime.now(timezone(timedelta(hours=-4), 'EST'))
    print(now)
    twenty_four_hours_ago = now - timedelta(hours=24)
    print(twenty_four_hours_ago)
    post = db.query(models.Post).filter((cast(models.Post.created_at,Date)) > twenty_four_hours_ago).all()
    #printing post above without the .first() shows teh query
    if not post:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, detail =f"Last post not found" )
    return post
```

The output seems to be outputting the correct values on the python side.

```
now = 2022-03-18 07:25:12.537947-04:00
twenty_four_hours_ago=2022-03-17 07:25:12.537947-04:00
```

But when it compares to created at it does not find a date earlier than 2022-03-18 00:00:00-04:00

The format of created_at is below.  It is a timestamp with timezone datatype.

```
2022-03-18 07:20:25.543046-04
```

Hoping someone can help me figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: 1) What is the Postgres data type for `created_at`? 2) Are you really looking for date or timestamp > 25 hrs ago? 3) "But when it compares to created at it does not find a date earlier than 2022-03-18 00:00:00-04:00" does not make sense when you show `2022-03-17 07:25:12.537947-04:00` in output? Add answers as update to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing the filter to the following and it works.

```
post = db.query(models.Post).filter(models.Post.created_at.between(twenty_four_hours_ago, now)).all()
```